# Is it possible to follow a chain of Foreign Key references in a single query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I have a database with two (relevant) tables: `Actions` and `Documents` and am querying it using LINQ.

An Action points to its input Document and a Document points back to the Action that created it, so `Action.Document` and `Document.SourceAction`.

By following back these relations we get a processing chain of alternating actions and documents.

```
Final Document-> Last Action-> Middle Document-> First Action-> Source Document
```

When a document doesn't have a source action, it is the original source document.

I'm using the following query in LINQPad to gather all the actions in such a chain and output them:

```
var actions = new List<LINQPad.User.Action>();
var action = Actions.Where(a => a.Id == 1240).First();
while (action != null) {
    actions.Add(action);
    action = action.Document != null ? action.Document.SourceAction : null;
}
actions.Dump();
```

This query works fine, but it of course fires a SQL query for every action.

Is there a way to get all these actions in a single LINQ query?

Comment: Thanks for the link, there's definitely interesting things in (and linked from) there. I'd been searching for "chain" and "trace", it somehow never occurred to me that this might be a "hierarchy".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a single query only if you will pull all data into memory. Otherwise you should do many queries.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to prevent those multiple queries. But this table tends to grow to millions of records, so loading it may also be unwanted. I guess I could always pick a strategy based on an initial count of the number of actions.